# Ruby: Why can't my test see my module level constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

In file `lib/outer/inner/inner.rb` I have a `ruby` module defined as follows:

```
module Outer
  module Inner
    NAME = "Inner Name"
  end
end
```

and in `spec/lib/outer/inner/inner_spec.rb` I have a test as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Outer::Inner, type: :none do
  let(:name) { described_class::NAME }

  it "has the right name" do
    expect(name).to eql "Inner Name"
  end
end
```

Running this test results in

```
 Failure/Error: let(:name) { described_class::NAME }
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Outer::Inner::NAME
```

The test can find the `Outer::Inner` module just fine so it's certain to have been required already.

Why can't the test see `Outer::Inner::NAME`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Rails` is doing something magic with the code in the `lib` folder that overrides the in-code module definitions.

I moved `inner.rb` up one level in the folder hierarchy and voila it works.

So `lib/outer/inner/inner.rb` becomes `lib/outer/inner.rb`